# Using data in router outlet components from common service

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

at the beginning I want to write I don't know very well angular and Im consfused with my problem. In my application I have one big component called ScheduleComponent, which include at top meetings collection and on bottom 3 components that change depending on the user's actions( CreateScheduleComponent, SuccessComponent, ErrorComponent ). ScheduleComponent and CreateScheduleComponent are using BehaviorSubject object called meetings from common service like ScheduleService.

The problem is with my CreateScheduleComponent because in constructor I subscribe observable meetings$ object from common service with meetings and in the same component I use method for create new meeting and inside this method I must emiting new value, because my ScheduleComponent subscribe also meetings$ object and I want to see all changes in my meetings collection(cancel, add) on the top, but this triggers my all subscription in (ScheduleComponent and CreateScheduleComponent) and I want to prevent subscription in CreateScheduleComponent.

Please let me know, how can I resolve this problem.

```
export class ScheduleComponent {

    meetings$: Observable<Meetings[]> = this.scheduleSvc.meetings$;

    constructor(private scheduleSvc: ScheduleService, private userTokenSvc: UserTokenService, private router : Router) {
        this.scheduleSvc.getMeetings()
            .subscribe(rs => {
                let meetings = rs.filter(meeting => meeting.clientId == this.userTokenSvc.getUser().id && meeting.isScheduled);
                this.scheduleSvc.addMeetings(meetings); <- Im not sure about this line
            });
    }

    hasCreateScheduleBtn(){
        return this.router.url == this.router.createUrlTree(['/schedule']).toString();
    }

    cancelMeeting(meetingId: number): void{
        this.scheduleSvc.cancelMeeting(meetingId)
            .subscribe(rs => this.meetings$ = this.meetings$.pipe(map(meetings => meetings.filter(meeting => meeting.id !== meetingId))));
    }
}
```

ScheduleComponent.html

```
<div>
    <div class="text-title">
        Schedule
    </div>

    <div class="schedule-info-box">
        <div class="schedule-info-text">Your scheduled meetings</div>
        <div>
            <div class="schedule-box" *ngFor="let meeting of meetings$ | async">
                <pre style="display:contents;">{{ meeting.startMeetingDate }}        {{ meeting.meetingTopic }}</pre>
                <button class="cancel-schedule-btn" (click)="cancelMeeting(meeting.id)" [hidden]="!meeting.isScheduled">CANCEL</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="create-schedule-btn" *ngIf="hasCreateScheduleBtn()" routerLink="/schedule/create">
        CREATE MEETING
    </button>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

CreateScheduleComponent

```
export class CreateScheduleComponent{

    @ViewChild('dateInput', { static: true }) dateInput: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('matSelectTime', { static: true }) matSelectTime: MatSelect;
    @ViewChild('matSelect', { static: true }) topicSelect: MatSelect;

    times = TIME_INFO;
    topics = TOPICS;
    createResultLink: string;
    meetingDate: any[] = [];
    meetings: Meetings[];

    constructor(public scheduleSvc: ScheduleService, private router: Router, public datePipe: DatePipe) { 
      this.scheduleSvc.meetings$
        .pipe(first())    <- only first() prevents triggers after next
      .subscribe(x => 
        {
          this.meetings = x;
          this.createMeetingDates(x);
        });
    }

    createMeeting() {
      let dividedTime = this.matSelectTime.value.split(':') as number[];
      let date = new Date(this.datePipe.transform(this.dateInput.nativeElement.value) as string);
      
      let meeting =
       { 
        createDate: new Date(),
        clientId: 14,
        startMeetingDate: new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), dividedTime[0], dividedTime[1], 0),
        meetingTopic: this.topicSelect.value,
        isScheduled: true
      };

      this.scheduleSvc.createMeeting(meeting)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(x => 
          { 
            this.createResultLink = '/schedule/success';
            this.scheduleSvc.addMeeting(meeting as Meetings);
            
            return of(x); 
          }),
        catchError(_ => this.createResultLink = '/schedule/error'))
      .subscribe(x => this.router.navigate([this.createResultLink]));
    }
```

ScheduleService

```
export class ScheduleService {

    private meetingsSource = new BehaviorSubject<Meetings[]>([]);
    meetings$ = this.meetingsSource.asObservable();

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    }

    getMeetings(): Observable<Meetings[]> {
        return this.httpClient.get<Meetings[]>(`${baseUrl}/api/schedule/meetings`, httpOptions);
    }

    createMeeting(meeting: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.post(`${baseUrl}/api/schedule/createMeeting`, meeting, { responseType: 'text' })
    }

    addMeetings(meetings: Meetings[]){
        this.meetingsSource.next(meetings);
    }

    addMeeting(meeting: Meetings) {
        const currentValue = this.meetingsSource.value;
        const updatedValue = [...currentValue, meeting];
        this.meetingsSource.next(updatedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to prevent subscription? That data is essential for determining data range, as far as I understand. After each addition data range should adjust according to the whole meetings array, including new one

Comment: After create new meeting in CreateScheduleComponent this code will invoke again 
      .subscribe(x => 
        {
          this.meetings = x;
          this.createMeetingDates(x);
        }); , but I dont need invocation here, because new success component will appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, the issue here is that `CreateScheduleComponent` is displaying a flash of the newly-created meeting before the page redirects to the success component.

If that's the issue, what you can do is force the subscription to `scheduleSvc.meetings$` to unsubscribe when a new meeting is successfully created, thus preventing the subscription callback from executing.

To do that, you can create an RxJS Subject in `CreateScheduleComponent` called something like `meetingAdded$`:

```
meetingAdded$ = new Subject<boolean>();
```

Then, in your `scheduleSvc.meetings$` pipeline, use the [takeUntil operator](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/takeUntil) to force an unsubscribe when `meetingAdded$` emits:

```
constructor(public scheduleSvc: ScheduleService, private router: Router, public datePipe: DatePipe) { 
  this.scheduleSvc.meetings$.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.meetingAdded$) <--------- add this
  )
  .subscribe(x => 
    {
      this.meetings = x;
      this.createMeetingDates(x);
    });
}
```

Then, in your `createMeeting` flow, trigger an emit from `meetingAdded$` using the [tap operator](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap), which is used for side effects:

```
this.scheduleSvc.createMeeting(meeting)
.pipe(
  tap(() => { <----------------------------- add this
    this.meetingAdded$.next(true)
    this.meetingAdded$.complete()
  }),
  switchMap(x => 
    { 
      this.createResultLink = '/schedule/success';
      this.scheduleSvc.addMeeting(meeting as Meetings);
      
      return of(x); 
    })
```

With those pieces in place, as soon as a meeting is added, the component should unsubscribe from `meetings$` and therefore not show the newly-added meeting.